# oracle sql query [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle11g, toad

```
Select
CPC.BAN,
CPC.IO_SEQ_NO,
CPA.ATTR_NAME,
CPA.ATTR_VALUE
from CPC_PROMOS CPC
JOIN CPC_PROMO_QUAL_ATTR CPA
ON CPA.SUBSCRIBER_NO = CPC.SUBSCRIBER_NO
WHERE CPC.SUBSCRIBER_NO IN (select SUBSCRIBER_NO FROM `Load.csv`);
```

The input file `load.csv` has data like

```
SUBSCRIBER_NO
123
456
789
```

When I'm tying to import the csv table using toad in my oracle query, its throwing out Syntax error in FROM clause.

Can someone please help.

Comment: The problem should be because of leading and ending characters of \` Load.csv \` those can not be used in Oracle but in mySQL.

Comment: What is  `\`Load.csv\``? Backticks aren't part of Oracle syntax, and table names can't contain dots.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to load a CSV file into Oracle and run a query against it. Is this CSV file on the database server, or on your client machine?

Comment: I doubt ODBC is related to TOAD - please set only relevant tags.

Comment: You've been told what's wrong. Though, saying that "its throwing out Syntax error in FROM clause" - which FROM clause? There are two of them (and could be even more). Try to be more precise next time, just to avoid confusion.